# Java: Console stops working when using javazoom

Tags: java, audio, jlayer

When I start playing music by javazoom library, console stops answer. I can write anything, but no response.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.AdvancedPlayer;




public class Main {
    
    public static void men(int i) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Filename.WAV");
            AdvancedPlayer player = new AdvancedPlayer(fis);
            player.play();  
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while(true) {
            int i = scn.nextInt();
            if(i == 1) {
                men(i);
            }
            if(i == 5) {
                System.out.println("i am here");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Is there solution? Or javazoom can't play audio and do other things?

Comment: please provide the code base through github

Comment: @AnishB. , i am new at this website, you mean, you want me to send you java-project?

Comment: Yes !! I mean that

Comment: @AnishB. god, i can't use github. i don't know how to use it. tutorial didn't help. maybe google drive?

Comment: @AnishB. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1A03E7m7A9_ymk5FCLOxg1xzSIqiyDOAZ?usp=sharing

Comment: I will have a look over this code to resolve your issue. What is your objective in brief ?

Comment: @AnishB. i want code to start playing music and i could write other commands and java will response. Now, when i write something in console after java start playing music, it didn't response at all. I think, it stays at `player.play()`, and will go futher after song will end. Thanks!

Comment: Hope for the best. I need to check. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you mean by "console stops answer" and "Javazoom can't play audio and do other things."

You can execute the javazoom play command in its own thread. While that thread runs concurrently, your program will be free to execute other tasks.

Do you know how to create and launch a thread? Here is Oracle's tutorial [Processes and Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html).